# Reencoding makes video quality much worse after 'rendering'

Tags: movie-clip-editor, encoding

I used Blender to cut video material into a ~ 4minutes video but the reencoding of the material looks really blurry.
Is there an option in Blender to keep the original encoding and not to reencode the whole strip again? (I did not touch any color balance or other parameters which probably would require reencoding).

However, I'm a noob and I just assume that the quality loss is because of reencoding, please tell me if that is the case. Seems part of the blure was added by the YT reencoding.

You can see the pine-trees in the beginning, it seems really blurry:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IeAwH0ictTs

Thanks!